# Nsight Compute Range Replay mode usage

Tags: performance, asynchronous, cuda, profile, nsight-compute

I just want to measure performance (IPC, Throughput, Duration) of application that contain some kernels and CUDA APIs. How can I measure 'real duration' of these application using Nsight Compute or System?

I knew that Nsight Compute Profiler is not for application but for specific single kernel profile.
NVIDIA Manual also said that Nsight Compute serialize all kernels for profiling each kernel exactly.

So on, I saw NCU support 'range replay, application range replay mode' not serialize kernel and profile metrics of concurrent kernels. Is that also profile CUDA API's activity like `cudaMemcpy()`?

I just want to measure total performance and utilization of some application.

The meaning of total performance is not just a single kernel or average kernel performance  like `gpc__elapsed_cycle.max`. This value means just single kernel and serialized kernel duration value.
I want to expect get the real duration value when application also has async kernels or CUDA APIs.

Comment: Sounds like you should use Nsight Systems.

Comment: For async kernels on streams you can use register a CPU callback, which stores the time

Comment: Thank you very much. But I also want to measure a HW metrics when using CUDA API like call cudamemcpy which trigger DMA in gpu machine calling lots of DRAM read or write operation. It also measured in nsight systems?

Comment: All three Nsight Compute, Nsight Systems and callbacks can log cudaMemcpy(Async) execution time. Nsight Compute gives detailed metrics for individual kernels and API calls, but slows down the system as it often invokes each kernel several times to get all metrics. The result nevertheless is very accurate. Nsight Systems mostly logs timing of GPU kernels and API calls and CPU threads from a system perspective. Callbacks are a way to get timestamps and individual timing measurements integrated in your program and can be used for debug or production purposes.